# Two "connected" different repositories?

Tags: git

Sorry if title of topic is not precisious enough, but I don't know how to name it :)
I have access to my client's GIT (on github) repository (pushing, pulling etc). Lets name that repo "origin". I want to hire cooworkers to work with that project. I can't give them access to orginal (my client's) repository, so I need to create my private git repository on bitbucket (lets name it "inner") and I want to give them access to that last one. Here is a problem - I have to pulling changes to "inner" repository from "origin" to pushing that changes later to "inner" to share it with my coworkers. 
From my coworkers side: they have to see only "inner" repository, can pushing their changes to "inner" repository and can pulling changes from "inner". 
From my side: I have to pulling changes from "origin" respository (changes from outside developers) and pushing it to "inner" to share it with my coworkers. Moreover - I have to pulling changes from "inner" repository (my developers), check code and - when code looks OK - I want to push these changes to "origin" repository.

In one phrase - I want to hide my coworkers from my client :)
I totally dont know whats the solution for that problem. Can anyone suggests me anything ?

Comment: There are 2 issues at hand. One is to sanitize any upstreamed commits back to origin of identifying information about the author of those commits. The second is the mechanics of pushing and pulling the commits around. For the first issue, one simple option might be for them to locally set their credentials (author, email address) to be yours, so their commits contain your info. Alternately, you could rebase and edit that stuff. Probably best to squash their commits down, get author stuff correct, and then get that pushed back. You might also look at code comments for identifying info.

Comment: @webcitron, you may take a look at a similar workflow, the Integration Manager Workflow: https://git-scm.com/book/it/v2/Distributed-Git-Distributed-Workflows#Integration-Manager-Workflow, in addtion to the comment by DavidNeiss